# UWP - DatePicker and TimePicker customization

Tags: xaml, datepicker, uwp, timepicker

I would like to use DatePicker and TimePicker on the same line (horizontally). My problem is these controls are too wide. So I customized them to reduce the content but I can't reduce the width because the flyout is too wide. So I search a way to customize the flyout or to have a different size for the control and the flyout.

Here is my DatePicker style:

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style x:Key="DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}" />
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltMediumLowBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                    Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FirstPickerSpacing"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="SecondPickerSpacing"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseLowBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                      x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                      Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                      Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                      AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton"
                            Style="{StaticResource DatePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid x:Name="FlyoutButtonContentGrid"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="DayColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="MonthColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="YearColumn" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="DayTextBlock" Text="Day" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MonthTextBlock" Text="Month" TextAlignment="Left" Margin="4" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="YearTextBlock" Text="Year" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="4" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>

                        </Grid>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To customize the flyout, we can edit the styles and templates of [DatePickerFlyoutPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepickerflyoutpresenter.aspx) and [TimePickerFlyoutPresenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.timepickerflyoutpresenter.aspx). And we can find these styles in **generic.xaml** which is available in the **\(Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.14393.0\Generic** folder from a Windows SDK installation. For different SDK version, the path is different and the styles and resources might have different values. Using the default style for `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter` in 14393 for example:

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePickerFlyoutPresenter -->
<Style TargetType="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="296" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="296" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="398" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource DateTimeFlyoutBorderThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerFlyoutPresenter">
                <Border x:Name="Background"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    MaxHeight="398">
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid x:Name="PickerHostGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="78*" x:Name="DayColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="FirstSpacerColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="132*" x:Name="MonthColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" x:Name="SecondSpacerColumn" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="78*" x:Name="YearColumn" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightRect"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterHighlightFill}"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Height="44" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Width="2"
                                Grid.Column="1" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                Width="2"
                                Grid.Column="3" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="45" x:Name="AcceptDismissHostGrid">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Rectangle Height="2"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                Fill="{ThemeResource DatePickerFlyoutPresenterSpacerFill}"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <Button x:Name="AcceptButton"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Content="&#xE8FB;"
                                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                FontSize="16"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                                Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                            <Button x:Name="DismissButton"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Content="&#xE711;"
                                FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                FontSize="16"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}"
                                Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

We can change the `Grid.ColumnDefinitions` to reduce the width.

But please note that although, there are `Width` and `MinWidth` properties in `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`, but change them has no effect. `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`'s width is determined by DatePicker. They have the same width. If we changed DatePicker's width, the flyout will automatically adjust its width.

Besides, in `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`, we can't change `ColumnDefinition`'s width to `Auto` like what you've done in `DatePicker`'s style. Because in `DatePickerFlyoutPresenter`, "DayColumn", "MonthColumn" and "YearColumn" are  populated with [LoopingSelector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.loopingselector.aspx), which uses a panel like [Canvas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.aspx) inside. If we set the column's width to `Auto`, `LoopingSelector`'s width will be zero and users can't see anything.

So there may be not so much things we can customize, and we'd better set a fixed width for `DatePicker` like following to make sure users can see complete elements in the picker or in the picker's flyout.

```
<DatePicker Width="200" MinWidth="0" />
```

TimePicker is the same like DatePicker. If you want more flexibility, I'd suggest using a new custom control. Here is a blog about [DatePicker calendar custom control for WinRT Xaml](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/05/02/datepicker-calendar-custom-control-for-winrt-xaml.aspx). You can refer to the blog and [the source code on Codeplex](http://xamlwinrtcalendar.codeplex.com/) to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply cusom style changes to DatePickerFlyoutPresenter of DatePicker and TimePicker, the customized DatePickerFlyoutPresenter style should be applied as application level. I mean, the customized changes should present in (App.xaml), since the DatePickerFlyoutPresenter is application level popup. If it is applied page level or control level, it will not take any effect.